# Calculate days between two dates ignoring year

Tags: java, java-8

I have lists of marriage dates in "LocalDate" type and I want to find the list of people whose anniversary is in next 30 days. All of the marriage dates are from past years like 1980, 1990, 2000...

I have tried to use ChronoUnit.DAYS.between() function but it only shows the number of days if the date is of todays and future day.

```
String str = "2019-04-24";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(str, formatter);
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();          
long dd = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(today, date);
```

The answer that I'm expecting is that if the marriage date is like 1990-04-29, then it should show me if this date is within the next 30 days or not. Meaning, if the anniversary of the above date is within next 30 days or not.

Comment: So, you want to take the "original" date, change the year to this year and check if the date falls within 30 days?

Comment: @MadProgrammer No, it's not that simple. The calculation should also work in December.

Comment: @RolandIllig That is true, but I'm trying to ascertain the basic requirements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the "basic" concept is, you want to take your list of dates and change the year to match this year.  The "catch" is, if the resulting date is before today, you should increment the year by one, so that if it's December now, you will catch all the anniversaries which occur in January.

Maybe something like...

```
LocalDate now = LocalDate.now();
int year = now.getYear();
List<LocalDate> dates = ...;
List<LocalDate> adjusted = new ArrayList<>(10);
for (LocalDate date : dates) {
    LocalDate warped = date.withYear(year);
    if (warped.isBefore(now)) {
        warped = warped.withYear(year + 1);
    }
    adjusted.add(warped);
}
```

Then you would simply check to see if the dates fall within your required range...

```
LocalDate limit = now.plusDays(30);
for (LocalDate date : adjusted) {
    if ((date.isAfter(now) || date.isEqual(now)) && (date.isBefore(limit) || date.isEqual(limit))) {
        System.out.println("~~ " + date);
    }
}
```

So, with same pseudo, randomly generated date, I can get a result which looks something like...

```
Input date 2019-04-19
+---------------+---------------+--------------+
| Original Date | Adjusted Date | Within range |
+---------------+---------------+--------------+
| 1996-04-13    | 2020-04-13    |              |
| 1986-04-24    | 2019-04-24    | X            |
| 1989-04-23    | 2019-04-23    | X            |
| 1960-05-11    | 2019-05-11    | X            |
| 1986-05-18    | 2019-05-18    | X            |
| 1984-04-06    | 2020-04-06    |              |
| 1997-05-29    | 2019-05-29    |              |
| 2008-03-31    | 2020-03-31    |              |
| 2014-04-18    | 2020-04-18    |              |
| 1982-04-23    | 2019-04-23    | X            |
+---------------+---------------+--------------+
```

And if we change the anchor date to something like `2019-12-20`, it could generate something like...

```
+---------------+---------------+--------------+
| Original Date | Adjusted Date | Within range |
+---------------+---------------+--------------+
| 2001-12-16    | 2020-12-16    |              |
| 2005-12-28    | 2019-12-28    | X            |
| 1988-12-31    | 2019-12-31    | X            |
| 1989-11-13    | 2020-11-13    |              |
| 1976-11-13    | 2020-11-13    |              |
| 1991-01-09    | 2020-01-09    | X            |
| 1963-11-04    | 2020-11-04    |              |
| 2001-11-02    | 2020-11-02    |              |
| 1980-01-11    | 2020-01-11    | X            |
| 1979-11-17    | 2020-11-17    |              |
+---------------+---------------+--------------+
```

So it's capturing the dates which land in next year.

*nb:* I randomly generate my test date to be within +/- one month of the anchor date so I would get better test data.

Answer (score 3):

The required test cases for this calculation are:

```
Today        Marriage     Days between
2000-01-01   ????-01-01     0
2000-01-01   ????-01-02     1
2000-01-01   ????-01-31    30
2000-01-01   ????-12-31   365   since 2000 is a leap year
2001-01-01   ????-12-31   364   since 2001 is not a leap year
2000-02-28   ????-03-01     2   since 2000 is a leap year
2000-12-31   ????-01-01     1
2000-12-01   ????-11-30   364   since 2001 is not a leap year
1999-12-01   ????-11-30   365   since 2000 is not a leap year
```

These test cases give a hint at what to do.

1. take the marriage date
2. try that date in the current year
3. if it's in the past, take that date in the next year.
4. calculate the number of days between today and that date

Step 4 will take care of leap years.

I suggest to write this method:

```
int daysUntilNextAnniversary(LocalDate today, LocalDate anniversary) {
    ...
}
```

The word *anniversary* already carries the information that the year of the anniversary is irrelevant, which matches the test cases above.

Then you can easily use it like this:

```
int days = daysUntilNextAnniversary(LocalDate.now(), marriage);
if (1 <= days && days <= 30) {
    ...
}
```

Here's the test code for the above test cases:

```
package de.roland_illig.so;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import org.junit.Test;

public class AnnivTest {

    // Interesting test cases are:
    //
    // Marriage:
    // - Jan 01 in leap year
    // - Feb 29 in leap year
    // - Dec 31 in leap year
    // - Jan 01 in year after leap year
    //
    // Today:
    // - Jan 01 in leap year
    // - Feb 28 in leap year
    // - Feb 28 in year before leap year
    // - Feb 29 in leap year
    // - Dec 31 in leap year
    // - Dec 31 in year before leap year
    //
    // Ideally the test would test every combination of marriage and today.
    @Test
    public void daysUntilNextAnniversary() {
        test("2000-01-01", "01-01", 0);
        test("2000-01-01", "01-02", 1);
        test("2000-01-01", "01-31", 30);
        test("2000-01-01", "12-31", 365); // since 2000 is a leap year
        test("2001-01-01", "12-31", 364); // since 2001 is not a leap year
        test("2000-02-28", "03-01", 2); //   since 2000 is a leap year
        test("2000-12-31", "01-01", 1);
        test("2000-12-01", "11-30", 364); // since 2001 is not a leap year
        test("1999-12-01", "11-30", 365); // since 2000 is not a leap year

        // Ensures that the marriage is not moved to Feb 28 just
        // because the current year doesn't have Feb 29. This happens
        // when an intermediate result is 2019-02-29, which is corrected
        // to 2019-02-28.
        test("2019-12-31", "02-29", 60);

        // In a non-leap-year, Feb 28 and Feb 29 are merged into one day.
        test("2019-02-28", "02-29", 0);
    }

    private void test(String today, String marriage, int expectedDays) {
        int actual = Anniv.daysUntilNextAnniversary(
                LocalDate.parse(today),
                LocalDate.parse("1996-" + marriage));
        assertEquals(expectedDays, actual);
    }
}
```

And here's the actual code for the calculation:

```
package de.roland_illig.so;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;

public class Anniv {

    public static int daysUntilNextAnniversary(LocalDate today, LocalDate anniversary) {
        LocalDate d = anniversary.withYear(today.getYear());
        if (d.isBefore(today)) {
            d = anniversary.withYear(today.getYear() + 1);
        }
        return Math.toIntExact(ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(today, d));
    }
}
```

As you can see, the test code is much longer than the actual application code. When dealing with date calculations, this is necessary. Even more when different time zones come into play. And leap seconds. And other calendar anomalies.

Comment: Yes, it's very similar code. I focused on not repeating myself in the code. And because of the magic number 30 I was worried that I might make some mistakes in the code because having only the 30 as a test case makes it more difficult to choose nice test cases. I also wanted to avoid splitting the date into a `(year, month)` tuple since they might be mixed up with other dates. Having fewer variables often means that the code is easier to understand. Oh, and I wanted to focus more on the process of developing reliable code by having good test cases.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't care about year at all:

```
private static boolean isWithinNext30Days(LocalDate date, LocalDate today) {

    int todayYear = today.getYear();
    int todayMonth = today.getMonthValue();

    int dateMonth = date.getMonthValue();

    if (todayMonth > dateMonth) {
        date = date.withYear(todayYear + 1);
        return today.plusDays(30).isAfter(date) && date.isAfter(today);
    }

    LocalDate alteredDate = date.withYear(todayYear);
    return today.plusDays(30).isAfter(alteredDate) && alteredDate.isAfter(today);

}
```

Comment: I think you need to set it to the current year to calculate the end date correctly. And I don't think you need a year at all to compare the start dates.

Comment: @shmosel what would be the difference? it's just a constant on both sides

Comment: A leap day could affect the 30 day calculation.

Answer (score -1):

Try computing this year's anniversary and finding the difference between now and that date:

```java
    String str = "2008-05-20";
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
    LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(str, formatter);
    LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();          
    long dd = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(today, date);
    System.err.println("YOUR ANSWER WAS " + dd);

    LocalDate thisYearsAnniversary = LocalDate.of(today.getYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDayOfMonth());
    System.err.println("THIS YEARS ANNIVERSARY IS " + thisYearsAnniversary);

    dd = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(today, thisYearsAnniversary);
    System.err.println("WHICH IS IN " + dd + " days");
```

Outputs

```
YOUR ANSWER WAS -3981
THIS YEARS ANNIVERSARY IS 2019-05-24
WHICH IS IN 36 days
```

Comment: For a different example, wedding was 2009-01-14, today is 2019-12-30. Expected output is 15 days (so within 30 days). In your snippet tHis year anniversary will be 2019-01-14 and in -350 days.

Comment: @allanshivji You should ask the exact same question again in December and see whether it will still work for you then.